# Debian - OpenVPN connects but no internet - Forgots iptables

Tags: debian, vps, openvpn

I have Debian 7.2 VPS server which I use as Nginx/MySQL/PHP/Mail host and VPN for private use.
For VPN I installed OpenVPN. After installation I was able to connect to VPN, but there was no internet connection throught, so I ran next command in VPS terminal:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to MY.SERVER.IP.ADDRESS
```

It fix the problem immediately, but just temporarily - after few hours of use, Internet connection throught VPN gone, and I need to ran command again in order to establish it again.

For client I use OpenVPN GUI for Windows, and OpenVPN client for Linux. On both clients - same problem, until command execution.

What I can do to prevent this from happening?
I thought that was APF Firewall problem on my VPS, but after disabling and/or forwarding VPN port in it, it still works only temporarily, so I think that's some problem with iptables.
I tried [this tutorial](https://www.debian-administration.org/articles/445), and rebooted VPS, but still the same.

My **server.conf** file of **OpenVPN**: [HERE](http://pastebin.com/Xq7gfnNh)

Answer (score 1):

Try saving your iptables rule with `service iptables save` . Run that after you have entered the desired rule and see if that makes a difference

Comment: As I expected: "iptables: unrecognized service" - Also there is no --save argument in iptables.

Comment: EDIT: The command you gave is possible under RHEL, CentOS, Fedora Linux distibutions.